# Change the totalScrollRange of the AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

How can I change the totalScrollChange of the AppBarLayout so it will scroll a custom range instead the measured height of the child with the scroll flag.

With the example the below, the idea would be to be able to scroll only half of the toolbar (100dp) instead its whole height (200dp), so the other half remains always visible while I keep scrolling.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by totalScrollChange , please explain more about your problem and what exactly you want.

Comment: An AppBarLayout view has a _totalScrollRange_ that is calculated internally at _AppBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()_. This is what defines how far the view with scroll flag should scroll, but I don't see any way to update this value in order to make the view scroll less. I tried with a custom _AppBarLayout.Behavior_ but nothing I did there worked out.